# Bash Script - Parse JSON results and set separate variables to be used later in script

Tags: json, bash, curl, split, jq

I am trying to take the JSON result from a curl and set each result for a particular JSON object to separate variables.

Using the following line in my script to retrieve results:
PROFILE=$(curl --user admin:admin -k -X GET https://192.168.1.1:8000/rest/call/profiles.json | jq '[.profiles[].id]')

with the above line my results might look something like this (but i could have 1 to many lines returned):

[
  "myprofile",
  "myprofile1",
  "myprofile2",
  "myprofile3"
]

Next, trying to determine the best route to set each id that is returned to a unique variable to be used later on in the script. .id could return 1 to 30 results so i'm assuming a do while loop and using the split command is in need here?

Any help is much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: If the amount of results can vary, you shouldn't be using "unique variables"... put them into an array.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but maybe this helps:

```
echo '[ "myprofile", "myprofile1", "myprofile2", "myprofile3" ]' |
  grep -o '"[^"]\+"' | tr -d '"' | while read x; do
    echo $x
    # do your thing
  done
```

output:

```
myprofile
myprofile1
myprofile2
myprofile3
```